# How can one park the hard drive?

Tags: c

How can I park the hard drive using C?

**Park:** To move the hard drive head from the hard drive to a safe location. This was done 
to make sure the head would not damage the disk when the computer shuts down.

I'm just curious.

Comment: There is no built-in support for this in C.  There may be some API provided by your OS, etc.

Comment: Many mobile hard drives are designed to park when they experience a change in G-forces. So you can park the hard drive by simply dropping it.

Comment: Where does your definition of "park" come from? Note the use of the *past tense*: "This **was** done..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's no longer necessary to park the HD heads, as most HDs do it automatically nowadays, and are pretty good at protecting yourself. However, should you wish to pursue further, look at this detailed description of [interrupt 13H](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_13H). Seems like the function 19H may achieve what you need.

But why would you like to do this? This can easily hard crash your OS, since your HD would probably be busy doing other things at the time (such as basic OS services, and other applications). And there's a good chance of data loss from this crash, as the applications probably won't have a chance to flush data to the HD - since you just parked it.

Comment: If you're using BIOS interrupts, you probably aren't worried about an operating system. Either there is no operating system, or if the operating system performs background operations it hooks int 13h.

Answer (score 2):

This hasn't been needed in many years. Modern hard drives will automatically park the read heads when shutting down. Also, as mentioned in Oli Charlesworth's comment, that functionality would have to be provided by some sort of device driver and its associated API. There's nothing in C that you can just call to do that.